# python supervisord program dependency

Tags: python, supervisord

I have `[program:A]`, `[program:B]` in my supervisord.conf

`B` depend `A`, means:

`A` should start before `B`.

How to ensure this by supervisor?

Comment: it could be worthy to take a look at [ordered-startup-supervisord](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-startup-supervisord/)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`supervisord` does not directly support dependencies. Your options instead are:

- Use priorities. Set `priority` for `A` to a low value and it'll be started before `B`, and shut down after `B`. The default value for `priority` is `999`.

  If you put the two programs into one group as well, that'd let you start and stop them in tandem, with the priorities regulating their start and stop order.
- Write an [event listener](http://supervisord.org/events.html) that listens for `PROCESS_STATE` `STARTING`-to-`RUNNING` transition and `STOPPING` events for `A`, then instruct `supervisord` to start and stop `B` according to those events. Have `A` autostart, but disable autostarting for `B`, so that the event handler controls it.

Comment: My understanding is that the "priority" approach above will most likely not work as expected.  Supervisord will indeed start processes in order, but e.g. [it will not wait for process A to be fully started before commencing to start process B](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/122) (that is, supervisord will ignore the `startsecs` parameter).  Instead, it will launch B immediately after A, which in many cases will not be (enough of) what you want.  This behavior [was already reported in 2012 but still isn't fixed as of 2014](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/122).

Comment: @miguno: then your option is to use an event listener.

Comment: @Cheche: priorities work fine, but if you expect priority order to also include *waiting* until the higher priority programs have reached running state, then that expectation will be disappointed. Note that Michael linked to that very same issue **6 years ago already**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Interesting... didn't noticed that. So is priority a matter of start up delay only?

Comment: @Cheche: yes, there is no implied direct dependency.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to take a shortcut, and skip reading the documentation about [event listeners](http://supervisord.org/events.html) and skip modifying your programs so they understand events, then:

Instead of starting program `B` (which depends on `A`) directly, you could start a Bash script that sleeps until `A` has been started, and then starts `B`. For example, if you have a PostgreSQL database and a server that shouldn't start before PostgreSQL:

```
[program:server]
autorestart=true
command=/.../start-server.sh

[program:postgres]
user=postgres
autorestart=true
command=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres ...
```

And then inside `start-server.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Wait until PostgreSQL started and listens on port 5432.
while [ -z "`netstat -tln | grep 5432`" ]; do
  echo 'Waiting for PostgreSQL to start ...'
  sleep 1
done
echo 'PostgreSQL started.'

# Start server.
echo 'Starting server...'
/.../really-start-the-server
```

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use supervisorctl: set autostart to false for program B, and in the program launched by A, write `supervisorctl start B`.

Example:

`supervisor.cfg`:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=false
pidfile=/tmp/supervisor.pid
logfile=/logs/supervisor.log

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory=supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock

[program:A]
command=do_a

[program:B]
command=do_b
autostart=false
```

The `do_a` program contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
#do things
supervisorctl start B
```

TBH it is the solution suggested by @drrzmr but I did not understand it at the time.

Comment: The problem with the work-around is that it requires `autorestart=false`. Fine for some apps, but not great for some others, e.g. a database.

Answer (score 3):

[this](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/122#issuecomment-6024816) is a great solution for me!

> A workaround that I have used is to set `autostart=false` on the
>   processes, then create a bootstrap script with `autostart=true` and
>   `autorestart=false` (a one-shot). The bootstrap can be a shell script
>   that calls `supervisorctl start` for each process. `supervisorctl start`
>   will block until a process has started successfully.

Comment: Seems like this could easily be an option in supervisor.conf.